# How to get a PHP array field value from a PHP file using jquery/Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, field

I would like to know how to get a PHP array field value from a PHP file using jquery/Ajax. In fact, I have three files: mapage.html , moslem.php and moslem1.php . You find below the code of each file.

The code of mapage.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout( test, 1000);
    });
    function test() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'moslem.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                var max;
                max = data;
                setTimeout( test1, 500);
                function test1() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'moslem1.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data1) {
                            document.write(data1+"<br>");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        setTimeout( test, 1000);
    }
```

The code of moslem.php :

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jqcalendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $max=$row['Id'];
}
echo $max;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The code of moslem1.php :

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM jqcalendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $notification = array('id' => $row['Id'], 'subject' => $row['Subject'], 'location' => $row['Location'], 'description' => $row['Description'], 'starttime' => $row['StartTime'], 'endtime' => $row['EndTime']);
}
print_r($notification);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Well, when I run the file mapage.html, it displays the below line every one second :

```
Array ( [id] => 22 [subject] => reading books [location] => at home [description] => reading some books. [starttime] => 2014-05-21 11:00:00 [endtime] => 2014-05-21 12:00:00 )
```

So as you can notice above it displays the content of the array "notification" which exist in the code of moslem1.php. Now, my question is how can I modify the line below to display just a field value of that array (for example the value of the filed "subject" or any other field):

```
document.write(data1+"<br>");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use php array and json

Comment: You need to convert the PHP array to json array at server and send the json to javascript

Comment: use echo json_encode($max); to deliver an json object which you can simply access in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `dataType:'JSON',` to your Ajax requests and change `print_r($notification);` to `echo json_encode($notification);` in `moslem1.php` then you will be able to access it as `document.write(data1.subject);`

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend :) ... It works!!...I will mark your answer as the best one :)